# Access to /users/recent/ (Recent Activity) through the API

Tags: feature-request, discussion, users

Would it be possible to have access to a user Recent Activity? 
I know that this is not a public information on the website, but I think that most part is public. I only see one Activity that should be private: when you down-vote something.

Having access to this would allow to write application that can notify you when a new comment has been added to a question/answer, when an answer is added to your question and monitor upvote/downvote on your question/answer.
It would really be great!

Answer (score 2):

Current API is read-only, and /users/recent info can only viewed by yourself (404 for other users). So, API shouldn't expose the informations that real site doesn't.

Actually, there is users/timeline option in API, that could be work around, except for voting processes.

Comment: Yes I know it's 404 for other users, that what I tell in my question, but some information are not private, in the my SA timeline http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/users/295/timeline) I don't see your answer for instance, It would be a useful information. May be my request could be "Add This, this and this to /users/x/timeline)"

Comment: @radius, yeah, It won't show my answer, because its your timeline. to monitor a question, you may need to call http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/questions/868?type=jsontext and to monitor reputation http://api.stackapps.com/0.8/users/295/reputation?type=jsontext, but still, yes. If all those info can get in one place that would be great.